# Let X have a density which is proportional to the function $g(x) = 0.5e^{0.5x}.$ Find the mean, variance, and MGF of $X$.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ have a density which is proportional to the function given below. After finding the
density of $X$, call it $f_X$, find the mean, variance, and MGF of $X$.

$$g(x) = 0.5e^{0.5x},\text{ for } x \in [1, 4],$$
and $0$ for all else.

What does it mean when there is a density that is proportional to the function?

Answer (score 2):

The author means that there is a constant $\alpha$ such that $f_X=\alpha g$.